# Dynamic pixel value based on window re-size and orientation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, height

I'm currently using the following to give me the height of a `<div>`:

```
var new_height = $('.div-1').outerHeight(true);
```

`.div-1` doesn't have a fixed height, the height is calculated by the amount of content within it.

I use this value to add an inline style to another element like this:

```
$('.div-2').css('top',new_height);
```

So if the height calculated is 590px I get:

```
<div class="div-2" style="top: 590px;">
```

I'd like to extend this a little further so that the `new_height` value is dynamic. So if a device orientation changes or the browser width changes I get a new value on the fly. I don't think my solution is far away, other similar questions don't seem to give me the answer I need. I'd like to avoid having to refresh the page if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to recalculate that top-margin every time the page is resized:

```
function setTopMargin() {
    //figure out and set your margin here
}

var resizeTimer = null;
$(window).resize(function () { 
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() { setTopMargin(); }, 75);
});
```

The timer ensures that the function isn't called too often while a user is resizing the window.

Comment: Works a treat, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!